# Should I incorporate questions from my topic-specific FAQ to the appropriate StackExchange site?

Tags: discussion, questions, community-wiki

On my website, I used to maintain a FAQ for {topical information}; I would like to no longer maintain it.  None of the information is proprietary.  Rather than have the information cast to the winds and only accessible via the [internet archive](http://www.archive.org), I have considered taking the most helpful/useful questions and creating community-wiki-style questions on the existing {topic-specific}.stackexchange.com website.

This is information I generated and am relinquishing that others have found valuable in the past.

Is this considered acceptable behavior or is it frowned upon?

Comment: FAQs for a certain topic usually go in the corresponding tag wiki. You could discuss this on the RPG Meta and see what other users think of the idea.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know each site had its own META.  meta.stackexchange.com forwards to meta.stackoverflow.com, so I just made the assumption that this applied to all sites; I did try to generic-up my question though.

Comment: @JoshDM If you had a question that applied to *all* sites it can be asked here.  (That's why SE links here.)  If you have a question that's specific to just one site, and that site isn't SO, then you should go to the meta for that site.

Comment: @Servy - Well, I did "edit" just now so it could apply generically, so if you do want to answer it in that fashion, then consider question asked!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like a great idea to me. I'd think that any SE site would love to have high-quality, pertinent, and frequently-looked-for information transferred to their curation, especially if the alternative is that the information disappear from the web.

I'd suggest checking in with the Meta site of whatever specific community you plan on posting to, however, partially as a warning ("I'm about to drop a whole bunch of self-answered questions") and partially to make sure that the specific material is likely to be considered on-topic and welcome. It's possible they won't want every single question for some reason, or they might suggest merging or splitting some of your questions before posting them on SE.

You will also want to pace out your transfer; every new question will appear on the front page of the target site, and at the top of the Questions list. Other users may be aggravated if you flood those lists with your questions, especially since they're already answered. There's a question posting limit anyways, but keeping it to perhaps three or fewer per day (and even spaced out over the day if you can manage that) would be best. (Thanks to [Benjol](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130064/benjol) for pointing this issue out.)

Also, be aware that you cannot mark your own questions as Community Wiki; you will have to flag them for moderator attention. Posting about your plan on the site's Meta will also help with this, since the moderators will already be aware of the need.

Comment: I'd also consider 'rate limiting' the transfer - I don't think the site would want its home page drowned in questions from one single user.

Comment: @Benjol: Excellent point; I'll incorporate that, thanks.