# Would it be sleazy to take my content from other sites and post it as StackOverflow self-answered questions?

Tags: discussion

I already understand that StackExchange considers self-answered questions to be OK. I'm wondering about a *specific class* of self-answered questions, those that merely rephrase the author's posts from other sites.

Like, would it would be considered "double-dipping" for points/reputation?

Specifically, I recently created [a coderwall "Pro tip"](https://coderwall.com/p/mqqr3w). I think the content of that pro tip would make a good StackOverflow question-&-answer, plus I believe a S.O. post would have more Google visibility.

Does anyone know if there's any precedence for this kind of duplication/adaptation being unwelcome? Or is it perfectly kosher?

Comment: Closely related, maybe maybe duplicate: [Should I incorporate questions from my topic-specific FAQ to the appropriate SE site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167166)

Comment: The main thing is make sure that your question is not a duplicate of an existing one.

Comment: That post you refer to isn't really a programming question, is it?

Comment: The main thing is to follow all the guidance in [help] @Josh, this includes searching for duplicates yes but if the question is crap people will try to close it. Either question or answer can be downvoted etc.

Comment: A Meta discussion based on [an SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17890904/) that seems similar to the one you'd like to post: [Should I ask a question that is easily google-able?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191653)

Comment: @JoshCaswell, that "topic-specific FAQ" question does look relevant. Thanks for drawing my attention to it! I'll take a look.

Comment: @juergend, you have a fair point, but I'm under the impression that StackOverflow *is* usually the appropriate place for Emacs questions (Q.v. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79659/180393) That said, I think my question remains relevant even if I created the self-answered question in SuperUser or Math.SE.

Comment: I see that my question has now been "marked as duplicate" but I don't think any of the current answers have been updated to address my (attempt at a) clarification in the "EDIT" section at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @JoshTilles i edited your post to address your specific question.  Personally, I try to avoid appending "Edit" and if your question is misunderstood like this one, just edit the question.  the more you leave the original intact the more likely it will continue to be misunderstood

Comment: @psubsee2003, thanks for the help & advice—I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 7):

No, self-answering is fine as long as you create a good question and a good answer.

Answer (score 7):

If you believe that the content will benefit the greater good, then yes, post it and self answer it. That's why there is the option to self answer.

> Yes! Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

I have directly benefited from people having done this in the past.

Also, you might consider searching for questions where your solution applies and answering those questions with your solution as well.

Comment: I would add that if you're answering questions you should "personalize" the answer to the question and not just copy-paste an answer.